# Can a Window Resize Event Detect the Browser Screen Width on Page Load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, jquery-events

I am looking for a solution to apply to a function so that it is called with the screen width size pre-detected when the page is loaded.

I have provided a snippet which demonstrates the resize event in action, but now I need to figure out how to have the screen width detected before the content is loaded:

```js
function checkWidth() {
  if ($(window).width() < 600) {
    $('#content').addClass('fulltxt');
    $("#content").each(function(i) {
      len = $(this).text().length;
      if (len > 5) {
        $(this).text($(this).text().substr(0, 5) + '...');
      }
    })
  } else {
    $('#content').removeClass('fulltxt');
    $("#content").each(function(i) {
      $(this).text($(this).data('originaltxt'));
    });
  }
}
$("#content").each(function() {
  $(this).data({
    originaltxt: $(this).text()
  });
});
$(window).resize(checkWidth);
```

```css
#content {
  border: 2px solid green;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}

#content.fulltxt {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="content">CONDENSE THIS TEXT</div>
```

Comment: By screen width I assume you mean browser window width?  Also as a side note `$("#anything").each` doesn't make sense.  Ids must be unique so performing an each off an id lookup is very odd.

Comment: Yes, I meant the browser window width. Would you know of a way to load this function without resizing the browser window first?

Comment: You can always call the method manually, `checkWidth()`, on page load, or tack on a `trigger('resize')` to the end of that resize binding to make it happen.  But your logic is changing things on the page.  If you cause the logic to happen before things that it is going to want to manipulate exist, it should be expected that you may run into issues there.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the information and advice. I guess I am just looking for a solution that works like CSS media queries, but with JQuery. I have text that I need to condense when the browser window is smaller in width. How could your suggestion be applied to the snippet above?

Comment: Honestly, i'd say if you could do it with media queries, do it with media queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I was making this more complicated than I needed to. Media queries seemed to do the trick, for the most part:

```css
#content {
  max-width: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: normal;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:600px) {
  #content {
    max-width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="content">CONDENSE THIS TEXT</div>
<div id="content">CONDENSE THIS TEXT</div>
<div id="content">CONDENSE THIS TEXT</div>
<div id="content">CONDENSE THIS TEXT</div>
<div id="content">CONDENSE THIS TEXT</div>
```